# How to effectivelly broadcast an array into an array

Tags: python, numpy

I needed to construct an image out of a numpy array. Each pixel should get an r,g,b,alpha value based on the integer in the array. To this end I wrote the following piece of code:

let r be an array with integers ranging from -2 to 0

```
print(r)
array([[-1, -1, -1, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   [-1, -1, -1, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   [-1, -1, -1, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   ...,
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

colors is a dictionary encoding the r,g,b,alpha values

```
print(colors) 
{-2: ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
-1: ['1', '1', '1', '0.5'],
0: ['0', '0', '0', '0.5']}
```

to get an image of dimensions a.shape[0], a.shape[1],4 I do the following

```
    r = r.astype('int32')
    im = r.reshape(r.shape[0]*r.shape[1])
    im = [ colors[j]  for j in im ]
    im = np.reshape(im, (r.shape[0], r.shape[1], 4))
    im = im.astype('float64')
    toimage(im, cmin = 0, cmax = 1 ).save(dir_to + '/' + 'label' + '/' + str(zoom) + '/' + str(x) + '/' + str(y) + '.png')
```

This code works fine, but has for an image of only 256 by 256 already a runtime of over 0.2 seconds. Does anybody have anay suggestions how to optimize this somewhat?

Unfortunatelly numpy arrays do not allow me to broadcast an array into an entry.​

Comment: please [edit] your post to provide a [mcve] - at present, it's not possible to run your code

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Divakar's solutions executes a bit faster than my own proposed solution, but both doe the trick and are WAY faster than what I did above.

Comment: Consider accepting one of the posted solutions that worked best for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way -

```
v = np.array(list(colors.values()), dtype=float)
k = np.array(list(colors.keys()), dtype=int)

sidx = k.argsort()
out = v[sidx[k.searchsorted(r,sorter=sidx)]]
```

For that specific dictionary, `r` that's sorted in descending order and ranges from `-2` to `0`, we can avoid `searchsorted`, thus replacing the final two (in fact also skip getting `k`) steps with something like this -

```
out = v[-r]
```

For many repeated indices for indexing, using [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) might be better performance-wise. E.g. for the given sample -

```
In [195]: r = np.random.randint(-2,1,(400,500))

In [196]: %timeit v[-r]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.06 ms per loop

In [197]: %timeit np.take(v,-r,axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This executes a lot faster, but it is still somewhat indirect...

```
    r = r.astype('int32')
    im = np.zeros((256,256,4))
    for i in [0,1,2,3]:
        for key in colors.keys():
            im[r == key,i] = colors[key][i]

    im = im.astype('float64')
     toimage(im, cmin = 0, cmax = 1 ).save(dir_to + '/' + 'label' + '/' + str(zoom) + '/' + str(x) + '/' + str(y) + '.png')
```